# Template matrix with std vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector, accessor

I've tryed to make a 2D Matrix template Class unsing std vectors. So far so good most functions work as exepted. But when I try to write accessor or getter and setter functions I get some problems.
At first this the basic layout of my class:

```
template <class T>
class DynamicMatrix
{
private:
    vector<vector<T>> map;
...
}
```

My first attempt were accessor functions:

```
template <class T>
T& DynamicMatrix<T>::at(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    return(map.at(x).at(y));
}
template <class T>
const T& DynamicMatrix<T>::at(size_t x, size_t y) const
{
    return(map.at(x).at(y));
}
```

but when I try to call gameMap.at(x, y) = objxy; the compiler says its a deleted function.

So I tryed getters and setters and came to the same result when trying to assign a Value.

Comment: First, don't call your member variable `map`.  There already is a `std::map` class, and using `map` just causes confusion.  Second, a [mcve] please.

Comment: My guess the bug is in `objxy`, but no mvce...

Comment: By the way, avoid vector of vectors if you can. A single vector can easily hold the data you need, and is much more efficient and cache friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what `T` is in your `gameMap` but I suppose it doesn't have an accessible copy constructor thus assigning `objxy` fails.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, indeed the "objxy" had no copy constructor and I totally forgot to write one because is has an array in it (looks like I need to learn the basics agan :D ). After writing a copy constructor and an operator= the errors vanished.